# SQL Connection Over Internet: good practice?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, networking

I'm working with a WPF/C# desktop application, and I need to connect with the database server over the internet to a static IP address, but in some cases, an sql connection exception occur because the bad internet ping and latency.

I also know some of the security risks that can be made from this. I'm already parametrized all queries and connecting with encryption.

So I start to think: this is a good practice? And what can I do to increase security and performance?

Comment: In general the will be a web service between the client and the database. WCF is a fast way to start and write this layer in the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, exposing your SQL server over the internet is not a good idea. That doesn't stop you from doing it, but: I wouldn't recommend it, unless the data is freely available and public domain (so it doesn't matter if someone gets access to more than you expected), and is trivial to replace (so it doesn't matter if it gets damaged). And **even then** I'd probably suggest using a service tier and keeping your database server strictly on the "inside".

Re encryption: that prevents intermediaries from snooping, but it doesn't limit what the user can do. A malicious user with genuine access could simply connect up and do whatever they want, bypassing whatever rules and filters you have in place.

Comment: If I disable the Windows Authentication and protect the connection with a strong password, this will ensure security?

Comment: I have only one user that can connect to the database. Disabling all other users will increase security?

Comment: @Guilherme how do you feel that would improve security? What are you protecting *against*? (also: windows security is probably less problematic that SQL security)

Comment: I'm need to prevent an intentional drop table, truncate table and malicious updates and deletes. The data stored on the database is important. Also, a select into some specific tables will bring confidential information.

Comment: @Guilherme right; your approach doesn't prevent any of those things if the user has permission to access the database. Your best bet is to write a basic service tier that does the data access *and enforces the rules*; having access to a web-service does *not* allow the user ad-hoc access to the database.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. One last question: how about the speed? A service layer will slow down the connection? I feel that this will double the time between "give me the data" and a bind into a report or datagrid.

Comment: @Guilherme not usually; it'll still be besically the same amount of data that needs to get from A to B